# What does it mean when a GCP route does not have a Next Hop?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I see some routes have Next Hop which is easy to understand because it means when trafic comes to IP 1.2.3.4 route to the next Hop i.e. 6.7.8.9. But some of them don't have a next Hop, only a destination CIDR. So what does the route mean? "When the traffic comes to 1.2.3.4 route to ______"?

Comment: Your question needs to be very specific if you want a fact-based answer. Wrong assumptions are the source of many routing problems.

Comment: @JohnHanley which details do you need to answer this question? Which details are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no next hop the routes forwarded to default-internet-gateway.

The **default route** is a configuration of the Internet Protocol (IP) that establishes a forwarding rule for packets when no specific address of a next-hop host is available from the routing table or other routing mechanisms.

The default route in Internet Protocol Version 4 (IPv4) is designated as the zero address, 0.0.0.0/0 in CIDR notation. Similarly, in IPv6, the default route is specified by ::/0. The subnet mask is specified as /0, which effectively specifies all networks and is the shortest match possible. A route lookup that does not match any other rule falls back to this route.

Refer this documentation for more information on [Routes](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes) and [system generated default routes .](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes#routingpacketsinternet)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the packet will be sent to the Default Gateway if there are no specific route.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to the documentation for this? If yes, could you edit it in?